# Difference between `function` and `() =>` with respect to `.call()`?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I know about using `.call()` and `.apply()` to set the `this` for a function call, but can I use it for a lambda?

Consider this example from [the MDN webdoc for Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
function greet1() {
    var reply = [this.person, 'Is An Awesome', this.role].join(' ');
      console.log(reply);
}

let greet2 = () => {
    var reply = [this.person, 'Is An Awesome', this.role].join(' ');
      console.log(reply);
}

var i = {
    person: 'Douglas Crockford', role: 'Javascript Developer'
};

greet1.call(i);  // Douglas Crockford Is An Awesome Javascript Developer
greet2.call(i);  // Is An Awesome Javascript Developer
```

Why doesn't the `greet2` call work the same was as `greet1` and is there a way to set `this` in the case of `greet2`?

Comment: ["Since arrow functions do not have their own this, the methods call() or apply() can only pass in parameters. thisArg is ignored."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: @Andy — _Perfect!!!_

Comment: Really boils down to they are a convenience shortcut but can't be used in all situations